# Why is an exe file compiled by gcc so big?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I wrote a very simple code and compiled it with gcc. After compilation I saw exe is 48kB. Why is it so big? Is it possible to decrease it's size? Should I use some kind of compilation parameters?

> gcc .\001_simpleMain.c

```
int func()
{
    return 0x1234;
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While your program starts running with the `main` function, there are actually other code that runs *before* the `main` function, whose purpose is to set up the runtime environment (like e.g. setting up `stdout` and `stdin`) and does a few other things before it calls your `main` function.

Comment: Related question : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246167/why-would-a-c-executable-be-smaller-when-compared-to-c-executable

Comment: In non-embedded systems with virtual memory managers, 48k is vanishingly small.   Does your compiler add debug info by default?  Full debug info bloats out executables by a factor of ~6.

Comment: Even though, apparently, you're on Windows, you might like the article [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: Funny, all answers are about how to fix OPs problem, but the actually question is about why this happens. Strange things happen here on SO.

Comment: Even with debugging symbols, that program compiles to 9448 bytes here (8512 without) - are you linking against a static C runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with gcc

-Os

Optimize for size. -Os enables all -O2optimizations that  do not typically increase code size. It also performs further optimizations designed to reduce code size.

-Os disables the following optimization flags:

```
-falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels -freorder-blocks -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc -freorder-blocks-and-partition -fprefetch-loop-arrays
```

Comment: How does this differ from existing answer?

Comment: Pleas answer the OPs Question.